# Problem with thread synchronization and condition variables in C

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I have three threads, one thread is the main and the other two are worker threads. The first thread, when there is work to be done wakes up one of the two threads. Each thread when awakened perform some computation and while doing this if it finds more work to do can wake up the other working thread or simply decide to do the job by itself (By adding work to a local queue, for example). 
While the worker threads have work to do, the main thread must wait for the work to be done. I have implemented this with condition variables as follows (the code reported here hides a lot of details, please ask if there's something non understandable):

MAIN THREAD (pseudocode):

```
//this function can be called from the main several time. It blocks the main thread till the work is done.
void new_work(){

//signaling to worker threads if work is available

    //Now, the threads have been awakened, it's time to sleep till they have finished.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&main_lock);
    while (work > 0)    //work is a shared atomic integer, incremented each time there's work to do and decremented when finished executing some work unit
       pthread_cond_wait(&main_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&main_lock);

}
```

WORKER THREADS:

```
while (1){

   pthread_mutex_lock(&main_lock);
    if (work == 0)
       pthread_cond_signal(&main_cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&main_lock);  

    //code to let the worker thread wait again -- PROBLEM!

   while (I have work to do, in my queue){
       do_work()
   }

}
```

Here is the problem: when a worker thread wakes up the main thread I'm not sure that the worker thread calls a wait to put itself in a waiting state for new work. Even if I implement this wait with another condition variable, it can happen that the main thread is awake, does some work until reaches a point in which he has to wake up the thread that has not called a wait yet... and this can lead to bad results. I've tried several ways to solve this issue but I couldn't find a solution, maybe there is an obvious way to solve it but I'm missing it.

Can you provide a scheme to solve this kind of problem? I'm using the C language and I can use whatever synchronization mechanism you think can be suited, like pthreads or posix semaphores.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to specifically signal the main thread that a job was completed(does the main thread need to do some special "work completed" action besides generating the next work item)? Or you use that signaling just to let the main thread know it can produce the next workload?

Comment: I have to signal the main thread just to let it know it can go on to produce more workload. It has to wait until all the workload has been processed and till the threads are again waiting. It is important to notice that the worker threads can produce more workload by themselves as detailed in the question.

Comment: Also it is important that I'm developing on OSX where pthread barriers are not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to handle this is to have a single work queue and protect it from overflow and underflow.  Something like this (where I have left off the "pthread_" prefixes):

```
mutex queue_mutex;
cond_t queue_not_full, queue_not_empty;

void enqueue_work(Work w) {
    mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);
    while (queue_full())
        cond_wait(&queue_not_full, &queue_mutex);
    add_work_to_queue(w);
    cond_signal(&queue_not_empty);
    mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);
}

Work dequeue_work() {
    mutex_lock(&queue_mutex);
    while (queue_empty())
        cond_wait(&queue_not_empty, &queue_mutex);
    Work w = remove_work_from_queue();
    cond_signal(&queue_not_full);
    mutex_unlock(&queue_mutex);
}
```

Note the symmetry between these functions:  enqueue <-> dequeue, empty <-> full, not_empty <-> not full.

This provides a thread-safe bounded-size queue for any number of threads producing work and any number of threads consuming work.  (Actually, it is sort of the canonical example for the use of condition variables.)  If your solution does not look exactly like this, it should probably be pretty close...

Comment: I know this is the correct scheme, but the reason why I don't like this solution is that, after all, your taking a mutex lock on every operation you are doing on the queue. Since I have a lockless queue this is the kind of patter I want to avoid. P.S. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the main thread to distribute work to the other two, then wait until both threads have completed their work before moving on, you might be able to accomplish this with a barrier.

A barrier is a synchronization construct that you can use to make threads wait at a certain point in your code until a set number of threads are all ready to move on. Essentially, you initialize a pthread barrier, saying that *x* number of threads must wait on it before any are allowed to continue. As each thread finishes its work and is ready to go on, it will wait on the barrier, and once *x* number of threads have reached the barrier, they are all allowed to continue.

In your case, you might be able to do something like:

```
pthread_barrier_t barrier;
pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, 3);

master()
{
  while (work_to_do) {
    put_work_on_worker_queues();
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
  }
}

worker()
{
  while(1) {
    while (work_on_my_queue()) {
      do_work();
    }
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
  }
}
```

This should make your main thread give out work, then wait both worker threads to complete the work they were given (if any) before moving on.

Comment: There are details not addressed in your answer. In the code you have written, when a worker thread can proceed after the barrier_wait it is stuck in a while(1) until the main adds more work. You can say that this is a detail, but this is important to me: I'm not able to find a way to guarantee that the worker threads will go to sleep before the thread can proceed doing other things.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to guarantee. In my example, the worker threads should be awoken immediately after the main thread has added some work to the worker queues and waited on the barrier. Upon awakening, a worker thread will inspect its queue. If there is work to do, it will complete the work first, then go back to sleep on the barrier, and if there is no work, it will just go straight back to sleep on the barrier. The worker threads will be sleeping on the barrier indefinitely, until the main thread adds new work and hits the barrier again.

Comment: What can happen in my example is that one thread finish all the work that has been scheduled for it and another thread on the basis on its local decision decides to give work to the first thread. In this scenario I don't think that the barrier is suited. However, I'm actually coding on OS X where there is no pthread barrier implementation.

Comment: I think you should look at @Nemo's solution, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have "new job" queue, which is managed by the main thread? The main thread could dish out 1 job at a time to each worker thread. The main thread would also listen for completed jobs by the workers. If a worker thread finds a new job that needs doing just add it to the "new job" queue and the main thread will distribute it.

Pseudocode:

```
JobQueue NewJobs;
Job JobForWorker[NUM_WORKERS];

workerthread()
{
  while(wait for new job)
  {
    do job (this may include adding new jobs to NewJobs queue)
    signal job complete to main thread
  }
}

main thread()
{
  while(whatever)
  {
    wait for job completion on any worker thread
    now a worker thread is free put a new job on it
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how your answer addresses my problem. It is fine to change the scheme I proposed or try a different solution, but I'm missing your point.

Comment: Could you put more code in? The code you have included doesn't really tell me anything! - as such I don't think I understand your initial problem (if what I've suggested doesn't answer it).

Comment: I'm not sure how my scheme doesn't address your issue, but then I do have to make certain assumptions. Can you explain in different words why that line in particular is "a problem"? - what problem happens?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you have here is a variation on the [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem). What you are doing is writing up an ad-hoc implementation of a counting semaphore (one that is used to provide more than just mutual exclusion).

If I've read your question right, what you are trying to do is have the worker threads block until there is a unit of work available and then perform a unit of work once it becomes available. Your issue is with the case where there is too much work available and the main thread tries to unblock a worker that is already working. I would structure your code as follows.

```
sem_t main_sem;
sem_init(&main_sem, 0, 0);

void new_work() {
    sem_post(&main_sem);
    pthread_cond_wait(&main_cond);
}

void do_work() {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&main_sem);
        // do stuff
        // do more stuff
        pthread_cond_signal(&main_sem);
    }
}
```

Now, if the worker threads generate more work then they can simply `sem_post` to the semaphore and simply defer the `pthread_cond_signal` till all the work is done.

Note however, if you actually need the main thread to always block when the worker is working, it's not useful to push the work to another thread when you could just call a function that does the work.

Comment: You understood the problem,however there is an issue with your proposed solution. Suppose the worker threads are 2. The cond_wait called by the main is waiting for exactly one signal from one thread, to what happens if one thread signal the main and the other is still processing some work? The second thread will eventually signal the main, but the main thread doesn't have called a cond_wait yet, possibly. The main thread must wait until every other thread have finished all the workload available.